# Network Patch Panel Connections

Tags: networking

So i have a client where we just installed a network rack system with 2 48 port patch panels and 2 48 port switches.  Traditionally I would patch down the ports to the switch on a as needed basis.  Meaning I would only connect from the patch panel to the switch if the connection was going to be used.  My colleague and the client want to just patch all the ports down to the switch even if the connection would not be used.  My argument is that you should only patch down the connections that are needed at the time they are needed.

Who is right and what are the pros and cons of each position?

Comment: You're both right - this is purely an opinion-based question, which is why I'm flagging it. Ultimately, in my opinion, the client is paying you to do as he or she asks, so patch the entire panel and cash the check. But still, not really a good SF question.

Comment: Definitely opinion based.  I prefer to wire them all at once. Less likely to make a ratsnest if you do it all when you have the right cables on hand and time to pretty it up.

Comment: @John - almost there mate to being able to simply cast close votes! :)

Comment: I have to agree with Grant. I used to cable up sites frequently and most tend to like to do it all at once for several reasons. It is cheaper if you are contracting to have it all done on the same trip. It is much easier to route cables without creating tangles and ugliness if switch groups are all routed at the same time. As far as reasons to do it the other way, if you label everything, it is easier to label end to end as you're putting them in, and if you don't know end to end when you install, it can be a pain to put ptags or ptouch flags on cable ends in a tied bundle later on.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is likely to be closed as "opinion based"...as there really isn't a right/wrong here.

Patch them all down...nice and pretty if possible using custom length cabling and/or cable management.

Then handle it all in the switches.  Disable ports that aren't in use or to be used.  It will look nice, save time later, and allow for whoever is going to manage it to simply change a setting in the switch from their desk vs. running a cable when needed.